# Swift 4 - универсальная функция Json Decode

Tags: json, swift, функции, decode

Есть следующий код, но он не работает как ожидается т.к. Swift выдает ошибки.

```
import UIKit

enum ObjectStatus: String, Codable {
    case Arm = "Arm"
    case Disarm = "Disarm"
}

struct Testobject: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String?
    var city: String
    var status: ObjectStatus
    //var active: Bool
}

func decodejson<T>(_ value:String) -> T? {
    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    let decode = try jsonDecoder.decode(T.self as! Codable, from: input_json.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    dump(decode)
}


let input_json = "{\"status\": \"Arm\", \"id\" : 1,\"name\" : null,\"city\" : \"Moscow\", \"active\": true}"


if let my_object = decodejson<Testobject>(input_json)
{
    dump(my_object)
}
```

Я пытаюсь написать одну функцию декодирования и передать в нее json и тип целевого объекта, в который должен декодироваться json. Что бы не писать для каждого объекта свою функцию декодирования

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас нет `return` в `func decodejson` + тип `Т` может не отвечать `Codable` и вы неправильно вызывали дженерик функцию (ей нужно явно указать тип возвращаемого значения)

```
enum ObjectStatus: String, Codable {
    case Arm = "Arm"
    case Disarm = "Disarm"
}

struct Testobject: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String?
    var city: String
    var status: ObjectStatus
    //var active: Bool
}

func decodejson<T: Codable>(_ value:String) -> T? {
    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    let decode = try? jsonDecoder.decode(T.self, from: input_json.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    dump(decode)
    return decode
}


 let input_json = "{\"status\": \"Arm\", \"id\" : 1,\"name\" : null,\"city\" : \"Moscow\", \"active\": true}"


if let my_object: Testobject = decodejson(input_json) {
    dump(my_object)
}
```

Comment: Это то, что нужно. По моему опыту в C#, где <T> не нужно указывать чему отвечает и просто кодирует/декодирует объект вне зависимости от типа, Swift вводит в заблуждения в использовании <T>

Comment: не уверен если я правильнол понимаю вас смутило `decodejson<T: Codable>` и если говрить языком C# то это ограничение типа и судя по тому что описано тут https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters  ограничение типа тоже довольно часто применяется в C#. А в данном случае `JSONDecoder().decode` принимает только тип `Decodable` или `Codable` который включает `Decodable`

Comment: Почти, но если точнее то в c# cериализация и десерелизация объекта в json или xml не требует указания какого либо типа или интрфейса (протокола) и по этому можно писать просто <T>. Ожидания от swift такого же функционала и привело в заблуждение